# Add Thousands Separator to matplotlib subplot bar label

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to add a thousands separator to a bar chart subplot.

I have a comma function

```
def comma(x, pos): 
    return format(x, "6,.0f")
```

and an autolabel function

```
def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.0*height, '%d'%int(height),
                    ha='center', va='bottom')

rects = ax.bar(ind+width, bar_values, width, color='orange', align='center')
```

I can call use the comma function for the y axis using

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tkr.FuncFormatter(comma))
```

How could I use the comma function while drawing the rects?

Comment: thanks @tcaswell for pointing me in the right direction. I ended up using '{:,.0f}'.format(height) and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change how you format the string:

```
def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.0*height, comma(height),
                    ha='center', va='bottom')
```